# Powershell: How to remove first empty blank line in console output of an array?

Tags: powershell, blank-line

I have some code ([tio.run](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyW1IjW/tKSgtETBVsFBg0sBCJRAhIJzfm5BUWpxcWZ@ngIcWCk4O3uGhCi4F@WXFiiYKOkgaQjPTCnJUEADVgrGhhYGKOo8UjPTM0ow1JlYGlgocWlyqZQlFgHdgnCYXklRZq6GpkKNQnBqTmpyiW4wUCAvXUEJYlAN2N4amHOVuFKTM/IVdNEA2FjsUv//AwA)), which output to console:

```
$exeoutput = @(
    "     Compression          : CCITT Group 4",
    "     Width                : 3180",
    "     Height               : 4908"
)
$var = $exeoutput.trim() | Select-String "Height|Width|Compress"
echo ----------------
$var
echo ---------------
```

Output is

```
----------------

Compression          : CCITT Group 4
Width                : 3180
Height               : 4908
----------------
```

How to remove first empty blank line after upper `----------------` from console output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element of the `$var` variable is of the `MatchInfo` type. You need to cast them to `string` as follows:

```
[string[]]$var
```

or

```
$var.foreach([string])
```

Read [ForEach and Where magic methods](https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/10/22/foreach-and-where-magic-methods/):

> ### ForEach(type convertToType)
>
> Unique to the `ForEach` method, you can pass a type into the `ForEach`
>   method if you want to convert every item in a collection into another
>   type.  For example, imagine you have a collection of objects and you
>   want to convert those objects into their string equivalent.  Here is
>   what that would look like with the `ForEach` method:
>
> ```
> # Get a collection of processes
> $processes = Get-Process
> # Convert the objects in that collection into their string equivalent
> $processes.foreach([string])
> ```
>
> You could have performed the same task by typecasting the collection
>   into an array of type string (e.g. `[string[]]$processes`), and
>   typecasting the array is in fact significantly faster, however there’s
>   a very good chance you wouldn’t even notice the difference in
>   execution time unless you were working with a very, very large
>   collection.  Despite the time difference, I will tend to prefer the
>   ForEach method syntax in certain situations if it allows me to
>   maintain elegance in the implementation by avoiding extra round
>   brackets in the scripts I write.

**Example** code snippet (updated with regard to the [Lee_Dailey's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55086267/powershell-how-to-remove-first-empty-blank-line-in-console-output-of-an-array#comment96920474_55086745)):

```
$var = $exeoutput.trim() | Select-String "Height|Width|Compress"
'-' * 15
$var.foreach([string])
'-' * 15
```

Result:

```
---------------
Compression          : CCITT Group 4
Width                : 3180
Height               : 4908
---------------
```

Note that `echo` is an alias for [`Write-Output` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-6):

> This cmdlet is typically used in scripts to display strings and other
>   objects on the console. However, because the default behavior is to
>   display the objects at the end of a pipeline, **it is generally not
>   necessary to use the cmdlet**.

Note that [you can multiply numbers, strings, and arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-6#adding-and-multiplying-non-numeric-types) (see ˙'-' * 15˙ instead of `----------------`).

Comment: would it be better to replace those `echo` items with the actual cmdlet? a surprising number of folks are unaware that `echo` is an alias ... and that it is NOT an alias for `Write-Host`. ///// also, the OP seems to want lines of dashes, so this looks like a good place to demo string multiplication. [*grin*]